# how to run the java -cp command

Tags: java

my current directory is C:/workspace/parent/persistence

I have two jars within persistence in the folder path(src/main/java/resources/jars)

how do I execute the following command.

java -cp ./Example1.jar;./Example2.jar cm.f.c.h.h.c.CApp -e mypassword

So, the folder structure is

work-->parent->persist-->s-->m-->r-->jars-->Example1.jar;
     Example2.jar

So the work-->parent can be traversed by doing cd parent on work directory and so on and so forth.

do I give ./jars/Example1.jar or ./s/m/r/jars/Example1.jar neither of the commands are working, it says jar is not being found.

s, m and r are directories.  I tried other ways combinations, but none working.
Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your current directory is `C:/workspace/parent/persistence` and the jars are in `C:/workspace/parent/persist/s/m/r/jars` you need to give the path to the jars, so `./s/m/r/jars/Example1.jar;./s/m/r/jars/Example2.jar`

Your main class, `CApp` must be declared as being in the `package cm.f.c.h.h.c` , and must replicate the same directory hierarchy, `cm/f/c/h/h/c`, within the .jar file.

(And for future, please copy paste exactly what you are typing in your terminal, and copy pasting the exact output/error you get- this is much more helpful than just talking about an error you get)

Comment: This is what I type in the terminal:                            java -cp ./s/m/r/jars/Example1.jar; ./s/m/r/jars/Example2.jar cm.f.c.h.h.c.CApp -d neoflex7y

Comment: And the exception I get is :                                                          Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ..s.m.r.jars.Example2.jar
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass                 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass                             Could not find the main class: ./s/m/r/jars/Example2.jar.    Program will exit.

Comment: Example1 and Example2 jars are copied in s/m/r/jars.  They are both there.

Comment: @user2544188  you get that particular error because you have a space in the classpath definition inbetween the two paths `/s/m/r/jars/Example1.jar; ./s/m/r/jars/Example2.jar` This should be `/s/m/r/jars/Example1.jar;./s/m/r/jars/Example2.jar` , that is, no space after the first semicolon. The command you posted in your question does not have this space, and should be correct, though we don't know if there's other problems.